# deleted all migrations with __init__.py file django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have accidentally deleted all of my **init**.py files while trying to reset migrations

i have recreated the migrations file on each of my apps with a blank **init**.py file but some errors seem to pop up like:  no module named "myprojectname.users".

this is my filestructure, i have deleted some unnecessary stuff in this preview for simplicity.

```
├───authsystem
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   0001_initial.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│          
├───contact
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│             
├───products                     
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   0001_initial.py
│   │   │   __init__.py             
├───shop           
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py          
├───theepicproject
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │          
│
└───users            
    ├───migrations
    │   │   0001_initial.py
    │   │   __init__.py
```

Comment: Does your `users` directory have an init.py file? Show your entire project file structure. Every directory from which files are imported needs to have an init file.

Comment: paste this as code in your question

Comment: as you can see all of my app folders contain a migrations folder even my project file contains one for some reason, but still i get this error.

Comment: i have removed the database file, all __pycache__ folders, applied migrations but still.

Comment: But the error you have has nothing to do with migrations: your `users` directory also needs an `__init__.py` file (at the top level), as all your other apps. Show us the full contents of the `users` directory, not just `migrations`.